# Live CD stalls when installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, bug-reporting

Booting from Live CD Ubuntu 13.10 64bits, I can't get the installation page. Just a black page with a system prompt:

```
"numbers" BUG: Soft lockup - CPU#1 Stuck for 22s.
```

This repeats in a very short time. The only thing I can do is force a shut down. I tried USB installation with the same result.

This is all what it does: Start pc (laptop) with Live CD or USB, them, after BIOS screen, a black screen with two options:

```
0. NO Emulation System type 00 
1. NO Emulation System type 00.
```

Notice both are the same except for the first number.

If you select number 1, the same options appear again but nothing happens.

If you select number 0, the cd starts to move and a new purple screen appears for a few seconds, then gives way to a new black screen with a blinking prompt, the cd stops and after about 20 seconds the following appears: [ 32.080003] BUG: Soft Lockup CPU#0 stuck for 22s [systemd -udevd:114]. Every 20 secs, it's repeat but first number is [ 60.080003], then [ 92.080003]..

Hardware: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8600 @ 2.40GHz [Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6],
NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS (256MB) driver: 327.02

Comment: First guess would be to search for the error message including the number.

Comment: Thanks. This is all what it does: Start pc (laptop) with Live CD or USB, them, after BIOS sreen, a black screen with two options: 0. NO  Emulation System type 00 and 1. NO Emulation System type 00. Notice both are the same except for the first numer. If you select mumber 1, the same options appear again but nothing happens. (cont.)

Comment: If you select number 0, the cd starts to move and a new purple screen appears for a few seconds, then gives way to a new black screen with a blinking prompt, the cd stops and after about 20 seconds the following appears: [  32.080003] BUG: Soft Lockup  CPU#0 stuck for 22s [systemd -udevd:114]. Every 20 secs, it's repeat but first number is [  60.080003], then [   92.080003]...

Comment: I'm so sorry, it was not cynical, I gave in error sending response and had not finished writing

Comment: Sorry that didn't came to my mind.

Comment: @user208790 - You can click on the grey link _edit_ above the comments and edit your question... and also click on the x-in-circle when you hover over any comment of yours to delete that comment once the question is edited.

Comment: Same problem booting from 13.04 liveCD.  The soft lockup bug began initially when I tried to upgrade to 14.04.  I tried to revert to 13.04 through a liveCD (that has worked in the past) but get the same bug.

Answer (score -1):

you may try the old version, I've got the same problem on my laptop, and we have the same cpu.... I installed the 10.04 version, and it can work! So there may be something bug with  old machine and new linux kernel.

Comment: 10.04 is End of Life, lazybird.  There is no longer any support for 10.04 Desktop.  To that end, you should not recommend 10.04 Desktop anymore, especially since the current LTS is 12.04.

Comment: 12.04.03 is the current Long Term Support version, and it may work where 13.10 does not.